# Невозможно поставить интернет на Windows Vista

Tags: windows, wifi, драйвер, vista

О самом компьютере:

Операционная система: Windows Vista Business 32-bit
Нетбук: Acer Aspire One D270
Производитель Wi-Fi адаптера: Qualcomm Atheros

Вопрос:

Почему не работает никакой драйвер для беспроводной сети?
Я скачивал разные драйвера, но ни один не заработал
А то, что важно отметить: На Windows 7 эти все драйвера (переделанные под седьмую) работают!

Короче говоря, не работает драйвера для беспроводной сети на Windows Vista.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю: ты спрашиваешь о неподдерживаемой ОС с неподдерживаемой архитектурой? Под "неподдерживаемой" я подразумеваю ещё и популярность. Вряд ли тут тебе помогут. Рекомендую поменять ОС.

Comment: 7 тоже неподдерживаемая, но тпм работало! Но хочу найти решение, а если не найду, то тогда уже перейду на другую

Comment: Ну удачи,чё. Виста - это конечно да, отличный выбор.